# TeeChart 2014 and FastReport 4.9

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, teechart, fastreport

I have installed Delphi 2010 Professional and FastReport 4.9. A few days ago I installed TeeChart Pro 2014. The problem is that I can't make FastReport and TeeChart work together. I found that FR 4.9 supports TeeChart up to 8. Is there any solution that allows them to work together?

Answer (score 1):

Replied this [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14959&p=66289#p66285).

If you want to use a package that integrates TeeChart into one of its packages, you may have to rebuild the package integrating TeeChart in a similar way than in the QuickReport article [here](http://www.teechart.net/reference/articles/QuickReport.htm).
Steema supports the integration of TeeChart into QuickReport and Intraweb components. For the integration in other 3rd party components, please contact the 3rd party manufacturer.